# Create a string that repeats itself x number of times

Tags: javascript, string, repeat

I want to create a function that returns a string a specific number of times. I have tried with this.

```
function stringRepeat(word, number) {
    var string = "" 
    for(i= 0; i < number; i++) {
        string += word;
    }
}
 console.log(stringRepeat("grey", 12));
```

However, it doesn´t do the job. What should I change?

I have tried to change ”string += word;” to ”console.log(word)” and then it executes (but i get the ”word” written on 12 different lines- I want to have it in one long string.)

When I execute the existing code I get ”undefined” as the result. Why is this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you are not returning any thing from function.

Comment: @dfsq I assumed that was an artifact of the question as the code was run by OP (hence my editing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your function doesn't return the string it builds. So what it returns is `undefined`.

Add

```
return string;
```

at the end of your function.

Be careful that you're not declaring the `i` variable, which makes it global and could lead to other bugs. Do the declaration like this :

```
for(var i= 0; i < number; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function stringRepeat(word, number) {
var string="";
for(var i= 0; i < number; i++) {

    string += word;
}
 return string;
}
 alert(stringRepeat("grey", 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function stringRepeat(word, number) {
var words =[]; 
for(var i= 0; i < number; i++) {
    words[i]= word;
 }
 return words.join("");
}
 //or

function stringRepeat(word, number) {
var string = "" 
for(var i= 0; i < number; i++) {
    string += word;
}
return string; 
}
console.log(stringRepeat("fine", 52));
```

choose the one you like .